# How do you make internal files world readable on Honeycomb?

Tags: android

I am trying to load video files from my internal storage to a VideoView. I download these video files from a server and then store them locally using this code:

```
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

The documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal made me believe that these files would be created as world readable, but I don't think that is true.

Here is the code I use to load the file into the ViewView:

```
videoView.setVideoPath(getFilesDir() +"/"+ filename);
```

And here is the output I get from DDMS:

```
ERROR/MediaPlayer(4264): error (1, -2147483648)
ERROR/MediaPlayer(4264): Error (1,-2147483648)
DEBUG/VideoView(4264): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

If I change the code to load the same video from my raw resources directory, everything runs fine. However, I need to be able to download these videos and play them locally.

Are my only options to use external data or is there a way to make internal data public to something like a VideoView?

Comment: Have you tried external storage? If not why not since internal storage is usually limited.

Comment: This app basically has a large data file full of videos and images, we can't put these in the app itself because of size limits on .apk files in the Market. We only download this data once, I thought internal storage would be more persistent. We are only targeting Honeycomb tablets with this app.

Comment: have you verifed that getFilesDir() + "/" + filename is actually pointing the newly created file?

Comment: Also can you post your videoView code?

Comment: Never use concatenation to create paths. Use the appropriate `File` constructor. `VideoView` should not need a world-readable file, as it is in your own process.

Comment: I have checked to make sure that the path is correct in the debugger. I'm now re-writing to use external storage and see what happens. @CommonsWare Thanks for the tip for the file separator. If you google that DDMS output you will find lots of threads that talk about permission issues with VideoView. MediaPlayer can't read private files unless you open the file and pass it a FileDescriptor, but VideoView doesn't expose that functionality from MediaPlayer.

Comment: Note that you can always use `MediaPlayer` and `SurfaceView` if you don't like the interface of `VideoView`. Or, implement a simple `ContentProvider` with `openFile()` to return the `FileDescriptor` and use the `content://` `Uri` with `VideoView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare The ContentProvider solution pretty good, if I go back to internal storage I will go that route. I already re-wrote to code to use external storage and everything is working well. I was going to go the MediaPlayer and SurfaceView route, but I really just wanted to use VideoView and not have to worry about all those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommonsWare solution in the comments is repeated below, as it is the one I ended up using:

Note that you can always use `MediaPlayer` and `SurfaceView` if you don't like the interface of `VideoView`. Or, implement a simple `ContentProvider` with `openFile()` to return the `FileDescriptor` and use the `content://` Uri with `VideoView`. - CommonsWare